# Binding properties from view-model to custom element in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

UPDATE:

Other people have reported this sample works well for them. Sounds like I was doing something wrong but I don't have the code anymore so I can't check what was the problem.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have the following custom element with the following view-model and view:

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
export class Test1 {
  @bindable name = null;
}

<template>
  <div>Name: ${name}</div>
</template>
```

Then I have a this view and view-model using the above custom element (this is the welcome page in the skeleton project):

```
export class Welcome {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Test';
  }
}

<template>
  <require from="./components/test1"></require>
  <test1 name.bind="name"></test1>
</template>
```

My expectation is to see "Name: Test" but I only get "Name: ". If I use a string and remove the ".bind" then it works:

```
<test1 name="Test"></test1>
```

But I want it to update automatically whenever I update the "name" field in the "App" view-model.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I don't see any error in the console.

I based this example on the skeleton sample project from Aurelia. Version of aurelia-framework is 0.11.0.

Comment: did you try to use different names in the app and in the custom element ? I mean like appName and customName for the attribute if you see what I mean ? Aurelia is still quite new, I don't why but there could be a problem if you use the same name for the custom attribute and the javascript attribute in the app. Though I seriously doubt it

Comment: another thing, could you add the imports you did in each file ?

Comment: I tried your code, it works perfectly for me

Comment: Thanks sam. I tried changing the name and it didn't work. I added the imports and also explained a bit better where I'm using the custom element, which is the welcome page in the skeleton project.

Comment: Did you try using the latest skeletton app ? I had a problem in the 11 myself and anyway the 13 is the last one containing breaking changes, better to start from here

Comment: I'm using the last version of the skeleton which uses aurelia-framework 0.11.0.

Comment: Only one solution then, if your project dies not contain anything more than that then publish it on github or somewhere we can access it. Really no reason for it not to work

Comment: I can confirm the code is working fine.  I copied the code exactly and no problems. Did you name your custom element files test1.js and test1.html?

Comment: Yes, the names were correct. I'm not sure what was the problem. After some other issues I decided not to use Aurelia so I don't have the code not working. Probably I was doing something wrong somewhere as other people have reported it was working, so I will update the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The prop "name" in "Welcome" class should be bindable.

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Welcome {
  @bindable name = ''

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Test';
  }
}
```